# How can I supress MariaDB JDBC warnings?

Tags: jdbc, mariadb

Having the following code

```java
try {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionModel.connectionString());
    return true;
} catch (SQLException ignored) {}
return false;
```

I'm getting this warning when I put the right server:port but wrong user

`[ WARN] (AWT-EventQueue-0) Error: 1045-28000: Access denied for user '1234'@'192.168.0.2' (using password: YES)`

I would like to suppress every kind of warnings as I'm just checking if the connection was successful or not.